# I am not able to post in api/controller by passing an object

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

There is the api controller below. I am trying to post with Create Method. Another point is I can call a get method with paremeteres however when it comes to passing an object it doesn't work.

Am I missing something such as routing or any kind of annotation?

````
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Category> objCategories = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll();
            return View(objCategories);
        }
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public IActionResult Create(Category obj)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Category.Add(obj);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                TempData["success"] = "Category has been created successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(obj);

        }

       
    } ```


This is the controller below
````

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
   IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        
        return View();
    }
    
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }  
}
```

Comment: You're HttpPost attribute is wrong - rather than the type "[Action]" it should be the route name you want see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routing-httpmethodattribute-name)

Comment: Do you mean like [HttpPost("[Create]")] this?

Comment: if you want the route to be just the same as the method name (i.e. /api/Category/Create) then you don't actually need any parameter i.e. just have HttpPost(). If you do want it to be different, then you don't need the [] i.e. HttpPost("CreateCat") which would make the route /api/Category/CreateCat.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 for further information about attribute routing

Comment: I am sory but I don't understand what are you saying totaly. The classes above are diffrerent classes one of them is Api controller the second one is controller.

Comment: What's mean about `when it comes to passing an object it doesn't work`? Do you mean that `obj` cannot be received in the controller?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I meant.